# Why wont my model move?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Hey so I downloaded a free model but it wasn't rigged so in an attempt to fix it I tried making my own rig/armature for it. I've finished the rigging but when i tryied to parent the model to the armature with "automatic weights" (like the tutorial told me to)
it just didn't show up, so I thought that I needed to parent the armature to the model so I did and so I selected "automatic weights" and when I tried to pose it, it just didn't move the model. Im really new to blender and can't seem to find out the answer to this.

Comment: have you enabled the Deform option for all the bones that are supposed to move the mesh? If not, do it and reparent. If it's not your problem, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: For right now it's working but it's a bit off and know the reason for it, thanks for the advice